# Create a std:array of char from a char pointer without copy

Tags: c++, std

In C++, is it possible to create a std::array of char (or a std::vector) from a char pointer without copying data?

I know I can write something like that but data are copied into the array, which is not optimized:

```
#define  BUFFER_SIZE       256

...

char *buffer;
std::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> data(buffer, buffer + BUFFER_SIZE);
```

I would like a solution to pass data by pointer, without copying data.

Comment: Short Answer: No.  The standard containers own their data.

Comment: the standard containers are rather picky about who manages their data. Is there a reason you are not using an `std::array` from the start?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If you are looking to make pointer plus size act more like a container, there is `std::span` in C++20.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: my array contains raw data with bytes possibly equal to 0, so string is not a possible solution.
Actually I have a class producing data depending on Qt ([QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-1)) and I would like to use standard container class instead.

Comment: false premise: "my array contains raw data with bytes possibly equal to 0, so string is not a possible solution."  It isnt that obvious, but `std::string` can contain `0` in the middle, you just need to be careful with methods that assume the `std::string` contains a null-terminated string, otherwise no problem.

Comment: btw I didn't suggest `std::string`, but yeah that would be an option too

Comment: in case you meant `char*` with "string", then also character arrays are not necessarily null-terminated. Its just not a c-string when it isnt and you need to keep track of the size somehow

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: Sorry I read your answer too quickly, I though you suggested `std::string`, which can be finally a possible solution if it is used with care...

Answer (score 0):

No not really. Arrays and vectors own their data.  Strings are the same.

> I would like a solution to pass data by pointer, without copying data.

Well You can always pass by reference but of course if you change it in a routine .... well ...... it changes it.

For characters you can use a COW string (Moooooo!) or Copy On Write string. The idea here is that a copy of the string data itself is only made if you actually try to change the string. So it's kind of the best of both worlds. Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on your point of view) the standard library string isn't one.  If I remember correctly some older STL strings used to be implemented like that.  You can of course write your own in short order if you are reasonably C++ proficient, or you can likely find an implementation floating around somewhere.  I have one I've used for like 30 years which works well enough for my purposes.